# The Old PHP Symfony 2.6 Router System

Tags: php, symfony, router

I have confronted with a website that uses PHP and Symfony 2.6.4. I looked it by `php app/console --version` command.

I'm looking for whole routes to understand previous web developer's coding.

There is nothing in `app/config/routing.yml`

He has created multiple yml files about 100. They are under the `src\Project_name\ProjectBundle\Resources\config`

I tried `php app/console router:debug` and `php app/console debug:router` commands.

At the `php app/console router:debug` and `php app/console debug:router` commands, both gives this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\izmir\konakla\bulut\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/functions.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\firm\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 54
```

And the folders and files are like that:

```
app
blogimg
cgi-bin
images
js
src
vendor
web
composer.json
index.php
info.php
styles.css
```

But the system works well. I have looked everywhere, but there is nothing to learn all routes.

How can I learn the routes?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I will upgrade when I'm available.

Comment: I suppose the first step would be look in the controllers and see if they used annotations for routing.  But the fact that app/console won't run is a bit discouraging.